# Remove footer-sidebar

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the black strip in the footer?

I want to disappear

This is the site:

www.avocat.dac-proiect.ro/wp

This is the code HTML:

```
<div style="position: relative; height: 126px;" id="footer-sidebar" class="footer-sidebar widget-area masonry" role="complementary">
```

If you change the pitch ... then work to solve but can not find where to edit the file.
Could you help me please?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
<div id="supplementary">
<div id="footer-sidebar" class="footer-sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ); ?>
</div><!-- #footer-sidebar -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the background color in the element with class .site-footer.

style.css, line 2822

Comment: yes but if you put your height: X value does not change anything

Comment: That's because that style is defined inline (on the element), not in the css, so it is overwriting your css rules. You can try adding !important in your css, or remove the styles from the element.

Comment: Here I do not find those styles

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the right stylesheet and using the correct class? Using your browser's developer tools can help checking this. It's hard to help with this lines of code.

Comment: Do you know any special tool? I use the default inspection tool from Chrome

Comment: That will do. Use the element inspector to see what styles are defined on an element.